# Como excluir a resposta de um if se o input se aplicar a outro if?

Tags: c#, if

Por exemplo, estava eu estudando e me deparei com o seguinte problema: Se eu fizer um programinha pra me dizer se um número é múltiplo de 2 e 3, terão números que serão múltiplos de ambos. O código que fiz é o seguinte:

```
           double n1,n2,n3,n4;

    Console.WriteLine("Digite um número e eu descobrirei se ele é multiplo de dois ou de três.\nDigite um número:");
    n1=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Um número só seria fácil demais.\nDigite outro:");
    n2=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Vamos deixar isso um pouco mais difícil.\nPróximo número:");
    n3=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Ok, agora estamos brincando.\nMe dê mais um número:");
    n4=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    
    if ((n1%2==0) && (n1%3==0)){

        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois e três",n1);
    }
    if ((n2%2==0) && (n2%3==0)){

        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois e três",n2);
    }
    if ((n3%2==0) && (n3%3==0)){

        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois e três",n3);
    }
    if ((n4%2==0) && (n4%3==0)){

        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois e três",n4);
    }
    
    if (n1%2==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois!",n1);
            
    }
    if (n2%2==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois!",n2);
            
    }
    if (n3%2==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois!",n3);
            
    }
    if (n4%2==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois!",n4);
            
    }
    if (n1%3==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de três",n1);
    } 
    if (n2%3==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de três",n2);
    }
    if (n3%3==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de três",n3);
    }
    if (n4%3==0){
        Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de três",n4);
    }
```

O problema é que, desse jeito, ele sempre dá um output repetido pros números múltiplos de dois e três. Eu agradeceria uma luz!

Comment: e o que você quer fazer nesse caso? o que são todos esses números n1,n2,n3,n4, não era para ser só um número? outra coisa, o operador de igualdade é `&&` e não `&`. Coloque o código todo e expliquei melhor

Comment: Usa ```else if()```

Comment: O código completo é esse aqui:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar essa lógica:

```
if ((n1%2==0) & (n1%3==0)){
     Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo de dois e três",n1);
 } else if((n1%2==0)){
     Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo somente de dois",n1);
 } else if((n1%3==0)){
     Console.WriteLine("O número {0} é um múltiplo somente de três",n1);
 }
```

Tente criar uma função genérica na qual você passa um N número, assim você não precisa fazer a mesma lógica para os outros Ns valores.

Comment: Resolveu, não pensei em usar o else if nas outras condições, tava usando no (n1%2==0)&&(n1%3==0), então como o if já tava sendo preenchido em qualquer das hipóteses, o else if nunca dava o output. Nem me liguei! Valeu!!!!